# ngClass compare number with array of numbers dynamically - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

I have something like this:

```
[ngClass]="{className: singleNumber == arrayOfNumbers}
```

How do I compare `1 === [1,2,3,4]` ? it works if I do this: arrayOfNumbers[0]

Comment: Your condition is not clear. When should the class be applied? When `arrayOfNumbers` contains `singleNumber`, or when `arrayOfNumbers` contains only `singleNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it easier for yourself and have the comparison in the ts and check the bool on template?

**HTML**

```
[class.className]="isInArray"
```

**TS**

```
arrayOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4];
//in some part where you want to trigger the check
foo(myNumber: number) {
  this.isInArray = this.arrayOfNumbers.indexOf(myNumber) !== -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to handle your situation

[ngClass] ="{ className : arrayOfNumbers.includes(singleNumber) }

This function's documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)